# Solving 4th degree polynomial with factorizations

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Find all roots of
> $$(x+1)(x+3)(x+4)(x+6)=720$$

I would like to solve it without brute-force, that is, not multiplying the factorization out.

I've done some similar problems like this before, for example:
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+6)=k$$
LHS can be regroupen as $$(x^2+6x+6)(x^2+5x+6)=k$$

Let $y=x^2+6$ and we're solving a quadratic in terms of $y$.

I tried to implement that on this problem, but there doesn't seem to be a way to regroup them.

Comment: This one is symmetric around $x + 3.5 = 0$, so let $u = x + 3.5$.

Comment: 720 = 6!, x=2 is a trivial solution.

Comment: Actually you can use your method: $(x^2+7x+6)(x^2+7x+12) = 720$ and now let $x^2+7x+9 = u$. It is easier than the other method.

Comment: My discussion in this [21 August 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/7UIZjaAUw8A/m/rB_ZrJkFcmIJ) might be of interest.

Comment: @TobyMak The numbers of the two question are not the same, hence the methods vary. This shall not be a duplicate.

Comment: @Cyh1368 "*hence the methods vary*" $\;-\;$ Can you show a method that solves your question, which does not solve the other question (or viceversa)?

Comment: @dxiv To be honest, the methods don't have a large difference. The biggest difference is that the linked question cannot be solved directly, it must go through the step of substituting $x$ with some other term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use your method: $(x^2+7x+6)(x^2+7x+12) = 720$ and now let $x^2+7x+9 = u$.

Then $(u-3)(u+3) = 720$ which gives two values for $u$. This is easier than the other method I suggested.

Comment: That works, but it's also a virtual duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2788566/291201) answer under the linked question.

Comment: I've already answered it in the comments so why not?

Comment: I don't see the point in voting to close the question as a duplicate, then also posting a duplicate answer.

Comment: The point is to show that expanding the brackets first and then exploiting the symmetry is much easier, as compared to directly substituting $u = x + 3.5$. The duplicate doesn't make clear which method is more appropriate for this question.