# How to quickly find the sum of the real solutions of an equation not equal to $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I recently participated in a mathematics tournament and encountered a question asking for the sum of the real solutions of the equation
$$(x-7)(x-3)(x+5)(x+1)=1680$$

As the math tournament was time constrained and I only knew how to solve this equation by creating a new fourth degree expression and then subtracting $1680$ from that expression then refactoring to find the real roots. However after coming home I did work this out and got the two roots of $x=-7$ and $x=9$ making the sum $2$ which aligns with the answer key.

However, I am still left wondering how this could be done in a more timely manner and my research on the topic has yielded few results.

Comment: Hint: $\,-3 + 1 = -7 + 5\,$.

Comment: Another Hint: take $x-7$ as $a$

Comment: Really the most useful substitution is $y=x-1$ in which case the equation turns into $(y-6)(y-2)(y+6)(y+2)=1680$, i.e. $(y^2-36)(y^2-4)=1680$. Now another substitution $z=y^2$, solve the quadratic equation etc.

Comment: Related: [If $(x+1)(x+3)(x+5)(x+7)= 5760$, what are the possible values of $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788449/if-x1x3x5x7-5760-what-are-the-possible-values-of-x), [Solving a polynomial in an easier manner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137384/solving-a-polynomial-in-an-easier-manner). For the problem here $\,\frac{(x-3)+(x+1)}{2} = \frac{(x-7)+(x+5)}{2} = x - 1\,$ so the LHS is symmetric across $x=1$.

Comment: In fact, the symmetry is what solves the problem. Namely, if $P(x)=P(-x)$ for a real (or complex!) polynomial $P$ , it is easy to see that $P(x)=Q(x^2)$ for a simpler polynomial $Q$. Namely, if $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$, then $P(-x)= a_0-a_1x+a_2x^2-\ldots\pm a_nx^n$ and this implies $a_1=-a_1, a_3=-a_3,\ldots$ i.e. all the odd coefficients are zero and so $P(x)=Q(x^2)$ with $Q(x)=a_0+a_2x+a_4x^2+\ldots$. Worth knowing!

Comment: $1680$ is easily factored as $2^4\times 3\times 5\times 7$ and all four factors in the equation have the same parity, so one of them must be $\pm 2$. Do we really need to solve a polynomial for this?

Comment: @DanielMathias That's assuming integer $x$, which is good heuristics but not a proof proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with the comment of dxiv, 
let $~y = x-1,~$ and let $~u = y^2.$

Then

$$(y^2 - 4)(y^2 - 36) = 1680 \implies $$

$$u^2 - 40u - 1536 = 0 \implies  \tag1 $$

$$u = \frac{1}{2} ~\left[40 \pm \sqrt{1600 + (4 \times 1536)}\right] \tag2 $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \left[40 \pm 88\right] = 20 \pm 44.$$

Since you are looking for real solutions, you must have that

$$y^2 = u = 64 \implies (x-1) = y = \pm 8.$$

---

**Addendum**

Actually, all of the Math, following (2) above is unnecessary.  From (2) above, it is immediate that the value inside the radical will be bigger than $~(40)^2,~$ and so only one (positive) value of $~y^2 = u~$ will be forthcoming.

Then **regardless** of the eventual computed value of $~u = y^2,~$ you will have the two real roots of

$$x-1 = y = \pm \sqrt{u}.$$

So, denoting the two roots as $~x_1,~$ and $~x_2,~$ you have that $~\displaystyle (x_1 - 1) + (x_2 - 1) = \sqrt{u} + (-\sqrt{u}) = 0.$

So, without bothering to solve for $~u,~$ you know that $~x_1 + x_2 = 2.$

In fact, with experience, you can see that because the third term in (1) above, $~-1536,~$ is negative, you could (instead) stop the Math after (1) above, rather than (2) above.

That is, (1) above, with **any** negative 3rd term, is sufficient to imply that only one positive real root of $~y^2 = u~$ will be forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve the problem in the following way: Define $t = x^2 - 2x$, then this quadratic has a real solution if $t > -1$, and in that case, sum of the real roots is $2$. Having this in mind, simplify the expression as below: $$ \left[ (x-7)(x+5)\right] \left[(x-3)(x+1) \right] = (t-35)(t-3) = 1680$$
from which it is clear that two such values of $t$ exsits, a larger positive number and a large negative number. Thus, the solution is $2$. You don't need to solve for the roots of the polynomial which saves a lot of time.

Comment: +1 (also) : for originality.  See also the Addendum to my answer.